# Embedded Jetty: Only handling one request at once

Tags: java, http, jetty

I'm embedding Jetty in a tiny Java application, my main method looks like this:

```
final Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(20));
server.setHandler(new MyHandler(someArg));
server.start();
server.join();
```

The handler is just serving files (and on-the-fly-compressed folders). The problem is that while I'm downloading one huge file (locally from my local server) and try to download a second file at the same time (from the same local machine) it will wait for the first one to finish before starting the second one.

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: Your QueuedThreadPool is rather low.  keep in mind that out of that pool you have (CPU cores * 2) threads already claimed by the networking stack (acceptors and selectors).

Comment: The maximum amount of users that will ever use this simultaneously is 10, so having 12 threads left over sounds perfect, but thanks for the warning anyway. I didn't know about that.

Comment: We probably should close this question as it seems about unreproducible bug that went out by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it wasn't Jetty's fault after all.
I'm not 100% sure where the problem came from, but I can download two *different* files at the same time and the same file twice on *different* clients.